# How to achieve more damage with K bullets?

Tags: battlefield-1

Is there a part of a tank or plane where K bullets can make more damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/Battlefield/comments/515dzx/bf1tank_car_weak_spot/

Damage to tanks is different compared to past games, it will affect certain parts of the vehicle and it must be taken out with more care than before.

Here is a quote from the linked reddit thread:

> Tip 1: First of all, damage to vehicles (planes and ground alike) is localised which means that shooting one part of the tank will hurt that part. You may have noticed it says that you've damaged a track or more, which means that you can focus your damage to incapacitate or destroy the vehicles.
>
> So when you are going head to head with a tank using AT nades, hitting the actual tracks will disable it on the spot which is great if you want a quick getaway. However hitting the cannon will disable it stopping the driver/gunner from shooting you. Combine both these and you can take one out easily with a little teamwork.
>
> Tip 2: If you are a scout and your against the light armoured truck, your K Bullets will not only damage it but also penatrate and damage the occupants of you shoot the right place (Noticed this one earlier when I killed the gunner of one).
>
> Tip 3: As long as your near the main village you have the advantage, tank drivers and the gunners do not have the ability to aim high enough to kill players constantly switching buildings and running to roofs. High roofs mean easy target for AT nades.
>
> Tip 4: Cavrlery have amazing AT potential so long as you dug and weave while your AT nades recharge. And you provide a great distraction whilst others come to help you.

Vehicles technically do have weak points, I would consider them as areas you want to hit the most. Hit both the tracks (disable the movement) and then knock out the cannon to entirely disable it. K bullets will do the most damage to the treads of the tank.

As for planes, truth be told I couldn’t find anything but I believe that the same penetration rule applies (read tip 2). So sniper bullets into the cock pit is always a good idea. And also try and shoot where the engine would be, it is most likely a weak spot. And if you can’t hit planes then aim a little bit away from it, so if it’s moving left aim a bit more to the left and shoot.